# Differential inequalities

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Let a function$f \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2) $ be s. t. 
  $$ \frac {\partial f} {\partial x}(x+2y) +\frac {\partial f} {\partial y}(-2x+y) \ge 0,$$
  $$ \frac {\partial f} {\partial x}(-x+y) -\frac {\partial f} {\partial y}(3x+y) \ge 0.$$
  How to prove or disprove that $f$ is a constant?

Comment: Is the use of the same characters for both the partial derivative and the arguments of the function intentional? If I understand correctly, the former are in $\mathbb{R}$ and the latter in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @zuggg You're misinterpreting the notation. It is the product of the function $F=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ with the number $(-x+y)$, and so on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General observation:

> If $\vec v(x,y)$ is a vector field such that $\nabla f \cdot \vec v\ge 0$  everywhere, then $f$ is nondecreasing along the integral curves of $\vec v$.

Both vector fields in question are linear, with stationary point at $(0,0)$. Classification of  such equilibria is well known, see [Figure 3 of Scholarpedia article](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Equilibrium). In particular,

1. the integral curves of $(x+2y)\vec\imath +(-2x+y)\vec \jmath$ are spirals emanating from the origin.
2. the integral curves of $(-x+y)\vec\imath -(3x+y)\vec \jmath$ are spirals converging to the origin.

Combining this with the general observation above (and a little continuity argument, since the spirals do not actually enter $(0,0)$), we see that

1. $f$ has a point of global minimum at $(0,0)$
2. $f$ has a point of global maximum at $(0,0)$

and conclude.

Comment: Wow the Scholarpedia entry is great...+1.

Comment: @ 40 votes : In general, I find your answer right. A little continuity argument is required.

Comment: @user64494 Do you mean you want me to add this continuity argument? For every $\epsilon>0$ ... blah blah ... $f\ge f(0,0)-\epsilon$ and  $f\le f(0,0)+\epsilon$ everywhere.

Comment: @ 40 votes: I have in mind the explanation why $(0,0)$ is, say, a local minimum of $f$.

Comment: @user64494 I'm not arguing from local minimum, going directly to the global. As in the comment above: for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a neighborhood of $(0,0)$ in which $f\ge  f(0,0)-\epsilon$. Every other point of the plane lies on an integral curve of the first field  beginning in this neighborhood. Hence $f\ge  f(0,0)-\epsilon$ everywhere. Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, $f\ge  f(0,0) $  everywhere.